# How can I Cache the data I'm reading from a collection of text files in a directory using a TreeMap?

Tags: java, caching, treemap

How can I Cache the data I'm reading from a collection of text files in a directory using a TreeMap? Currently my program reads the data from several text files in a directory and the saves that information in a text file called output.txt. I would like to cache this data in order to use it later. How can I do this using the TreeMap Class? 
These are the keys,values: TreeMap
The data I'd like to Cache is (date from the file, time of the file, current time).

Here is an example of the data contained in the .text. files.

and
are
as
at
award
awards
be
but
by
centsales
for
he
hello
her
hers
his
if
in
into
is
it
me
mine
no
not
of
on
or
s
such
t
that
the
their
them
then
there
these
they
this
to
was
will
with
you
your
yours
ä»–
ä»–ä»¬
ä½ 
ä½ ä»¬
æˆ‘
æˆ‘ä»¬
a
an
and
are
as
at
be
but
by
for
if
in
into
is
it
no
not

```
import java.io.*;

public class CacheData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String target_dir = "C:\\Files";
        String output = "C:\\files\\output.txt";
        File dir = new File(target_dir);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        // open the Printwriter before your loop
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(output);

        for (File textfiles : files) {
            if (textfiles.isFile() && textfiles.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                BufferedReader inputStream = null;

                // close the outputstream after the loop
                outputStream.close();

                try {
                    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textfiles));
                    String line;
                    ;
                    while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);

                        // Write Content 
                        outputStream.println(line);

                    }

                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That depends on how you want to store the data. Can you show us a sample of it and how would you like it stored?

Comment: I don't understand your question. A `Map` maps unique keys to values. What are the keys in your example, what the values?

Comment: These are the keys, values:TreeMap<name of .text file, name of class>

Comment: The data I'd like to Cache is (date from the file, time of the file, current time).

Comment: Date from the file ? -- you mean the timestamp when the file(that you are reading) was created ? as String? date and time separate?  or you have some "date" field in the file that you want to parse and use it ?

Comment: @FullNelson, I've edited my answer so that it allows caching file metadata. If it's some other info you'd need to store, please edit the question.

Comment: Yes I do mean the timestamp when the file was created. The date, time and current time are seperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache means to have it memory, you are already putting each line in memory  `line = inputStream.readLine()` and then discarding that in next loop iteration.

you have mentioned you want to store it in TreeMap, you need to decide what will be the key?, as the TreeMap is sorted, how do you want to sort it ?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class CacheData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String target_dir = "C:\\Files";
        String output = "C:\\files\\output.txt";
        File dir = new File(target_dir);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        if (files == null || files.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("File list is empty...");
            return;
        }

        // open the Printwriter before your loop
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(output);
        //( //comparator if you want something else than natural ordering)
        Map<String, DataContent> myCachedTreeMap = new TreeMap<String, DataContent>();

        for (File textFile : files) {
            if (textFile.isFile() && textFile.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                BufferedReader inputStream = null;
                // close the outputstream after the loop
                outputStream.close();
                String content = "";
                try {
                    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        content += line;
                        System.out.println(line);
                        // Write Content
                        outputStream.println(line);
                    }
                    //create content
                    DataContent dataContent = new DataContent(System.currentTimeMillis(), textFile.lastModified(), content, textFile.getName());
                    //add to your map
                    myCachedTreeMap.put(textFile.getName(),dataContent );

                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        String fileNameYouWantFromCache = "myFile.txt";
        //how to use it.
        DataContent dataContent = myCachedTreeMap.get(fileNameYouWantFromCache);
        System.out.println(fileNameYouWantFromCache +" : \n"+ dataContent);
    }


    public static class DataContent {
        private long cachedTime; //currentTime
        private long lastModifiedTimestamp;
        private String contents;
        private String fileName; //not sure if you want it

        public DataContent(long cachedTime, long lastModifiedTimestamp, String contents, String fileName) {
            this.cachedTime = cachedTime;
            this.lastModifiedTimestamp = lastModifiedTimestamp;
            this.contents = contents;
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        public long getCachedTime() {
            return cachedTime;
        }

        public long getLastModifiedTimestamp() {
            return lastModifiedTimestamp;
        }

        public String getContents() {
            return contents;
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "DataContent{" +
                    "fileName='" + fileName + '\'' +
                    ", contents='" + contents + '\'' +
                    ", lastModifiedTimestamp=" + lastModifiedTimestamp +
                    ", cachedTime=" + cachedTime +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you will have to **define "myKey"** -- that is how you are going to lookup your treemap.. you should decide how you want to store value (here we are storing the line/string you read from file as your map value)

Comment: I confused with setting the parameters of the TreeMap.

Comment: If you let us know, how you are going to use that data, that will also help us help you figure out the correct structure to hold in memory.

Comment: I need to cache the data from the text files to be reduce read time and help improve overall efficiency.

Comment: ok, pls. let us know what is the content/data of your file , what is the format, then we can see what is the best way to cache it. -- you can show us 1 line of your text file -- **if it is confidential, mock it**  -- also elaborate how -- in your program -- you are going to use this cache

Comment: I have added an example of the content stored in the .text files to my original question. I need to cache the current time, time the file was read as well as the data from the text file.

Comment: ok.. how are you going to use this data ?  what are you going to do with the cache ?

Comment: The data is being used in a stop word filter. Instead of reading it everytime     I would like to cache the data? If the data has already been read I dont want to read it again, I just want to return the cached lines.

Comment: umm.. so you are doing some kind of text parsing with **stop-word filer** this is a critical information..  you have words like this **and are as at award awards** do you want to index/lookup by a, b, c, or word index?   the question than is **what it your unique identifier for each line ?**  i.e how  do you decide to return line#1 or line #2 -- this will depend on your algorithm

Comment: The data from the individual text files are combined into one text file.

Comment: The question how do you match your stop-filter? for e.g. let's say you have  file #1 ( which contains stop-filter words)  and file#2 that you want to parse... now as you read file#2 you could encounter word tokens-- that you want to see if is a stop-filter or not. and may be skip it........... (in this case you could create stop-filter word index )  ..................another approach is you read file#2 character by character.. in that you need to match character by character so your index could be a, b,c,d etc.

Comment: ......another approach would be neighborhood/like pattern matching etc................ I have listed a very basic approaches, but **which approach** are you doing in your code ? than only we can define your data structure to cache/put in memory

Comment: There is a method already in place to handle the conditions you mentioned above. When the method is called it will check the map. The map needs to contain current time, the date the file was last changed, the time on the file, the name of the text files, and create a new class.

Comment: We are doing a lot of back and forth, Map has two parts  a **Key** and a **Value**  **I need** you to define your **key**   ------- **Map<Key, Value>**.......for .eg. Map<currentTime, List<files>> ? or Map<(currentTime,fileUpdateTime), List<filenames>> etc

Comment: Map<String, Object> = TreeMap<Name of text file, Name of class>

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for all your help. I'm in the process of making the necessary changes. I will give you a stauts update once those changes have been made and the program works as desired.

Comment: What is it that you did not understand? we can add comments but the code here is very trivial, so I need to know -which part you did not understood

Comment: I'm not fully uderstanding the map and datacontent.

Comment: Please read : [Generic Map Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) -- the dataContent is just a class which "contains your data"  -- after that you need to read --- [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) -- your question started with TreeMap, so I hope you know why you want to use a TreeMap -- correct?

Comment: Thanks for all the help truly appreciate all the time you devoted to helping me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate the rows of each file, you can do this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> filesAndContents = new TreeMap<>();

for (File textfiles : files) {
    if (textfiles.isFile() && textfiles.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        filesAndContents.put(textfiles.getName(), lines);
        BufferedReader inputStream = null;

        // close the outputstream after the loop
        outputStream.close();

        try {
            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textfiles));
            String line;
            while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                // Write Content 
                outputStream.println(line);
                lines.add(line);
            }
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                 inputStream.close();
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

Here, `filesAndContents` will map the file name into the content lines (in reading order). Because a `TreeMap` is used, the entries in the map will be sorted by the *natural ordering* of the file names (i.e. alphabetical order).

Based on your comments, seems like you want to only store the file metadata in the cache. If you're on Java 7/8, you can get this information from [`BasicFileAttributes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html):

```
Map<String, BasicFileAttributes> filesAndMetadata = new TreeMap<>();

for (File textfiles : files) {
    if (textfiles.isFile() && textfiles.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
        filesAndMetadata.put(textfiles.getName(),
            Files.readAttributes(textFiles.toPath(),
                BasicFileAttributes.class));
    // ....
```

If you also need the owner of the file you can get it trough [`FileOwnerAttributeView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileOwnerAttributeView.html) like this:

```
FileOwnerAttributeView ownerAttributeView = Files.getFileAttributeView(
    textFiles.toPath(),
    FileOwnerAttributeView.class);
```

You might also consider creating your own wrapper class for holding all the metadata you need to cache.

Comment: I confused with setting the parameters of the TreeMap.

Comment: Which parameters do you mean?

Comment: I want the name of the text files and create a name of a new class.

Comment: If your wrapper class for file metadata is called `FileMetadata`, then the file name -> metadata `Map` would be declared as `Map<String, FileMetadata> filesAndMetadata = new TreeMap<>();` If you're on Java 6 or below, the right-hand side needs to also include the types (`new TreeMap<String, FileMetadata>()`).

Comment: This information is to further clarify my original problem. My map needs to contain the name of the .text files being loaded and the data from those .text files. The map also needs to contain the date that the file was last changed. I need to check the file every 10 miutes to ensure it hasnt changed. If the data already exist just return the cached lines.